# Using Regex for YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS+/-TIMEZONE

Tags: apex, datetime, regular-expressions

I am trying to using Pattern Matcher to match the following format:

```
2016-12-15 09:20:08+1100 OR 2016-12-15 09:20:08-1100
```

I was not able to get the time zone properly for all the regions. Can anyone suggest how to do it for all time zones in a single Regex? I tried [+-] which is used for a plus or minus sign but it did not work.

Below is what i did with the Regex.

```
String MyRegex ='^(19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}(?:-)(0[1-9]|1[012])(?:-)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?: )(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?::)(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9])(?::)(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9])(?:-)(0[0-9][0-9][0-9])?$'

String s ='All levels approved2016-12-15 09:20:08+1100';

System.debug('****Original String'+s);

Pattern timeStmpPat = Pattern.compile(MyRegex);

Matcher m = timeStmpPat.matcher(s);

System.debug('@@@ Matcher' +m.matches());

if(m.matches()){
System.debug('### Matched String' +s);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is overly complicated.

Some things I would change to simplify:

- You don't need to use non-capturing groups (`(?:)`).
- You can collapse your hour/minute sub-expressions to `[0-5][0-9]`.
- You can collapse `[0-9][0-9][0-9]` to `[0-9]{3}`.

Even with all these changes, this expression will never match your `String s` for three reasons:

- It will only match if the entire string is an exact match, because it starts with a *start of string* character (`^`) and ends with an *end of string* character (`$`).
- Your GMT offset is `+`, not `-`. Your expression only searches for `-` offsets.
- Your expression only searches for offsets under `1000`.

---

Anyway, the following should work for you in `Execute Anonymous`:

```
String expression = '^(19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])((\\+|-)[0-1][0-9]{3})?$';
String input ='2016-12-15 09:20:08+1100';
system.debug(Pattern.compile(expression).matcher(input).find());
```

Or if you want it to be able to match just part of a string:

```
String expression = '(19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])((\\+|-)[0-1][0-9]{3})?';
String input ='Some Other Text 2016-12-15 09:20:08+1100';
system.debug(Pattern.compile(expression).matcher(input).find());
```

---

I would suggest dropping the range validation aspect of your expression and simply validate format. If you do so, you can simplify the expression to:

```
String expression = '^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}((\\+|-)[0-1][0-9]{3})?$';
```